# Add hours to timestamp column in dataframe based on value from other column

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyspark

How to write the following sql in pyspark

```
select FORMAT(DATEADD(HOUR, addHours, Coltimestamp), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') AS TransDate;
```

I have these two columns

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df= spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("2020-06-17T00:44:30", 2), 
        ("2020-06-17T06:06:56",3),
        ("2020-06-17T15:04:34",5),
        ],
    ['Coltimestamp', 'addHours'])
```

I want my result to have hours from addHours column added to the Coltimestamp in the new column in the same dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question.

```
>>> df.show()
+-------------------+--------+
|       Coltimestamp|addHours|
+-------------------+--------+
|2017-03-12 03:19:58|       2|
|2017-03-12 03:21:30|       1|
|2017-03-12 03:29:40|       3|
|2017-03-12 03:31:23|       5|
|2017-03-12 04:19:47|       6|
|2017-03-12 04:33:51|       7|
+-------------------+--------+

>>> df.withColumn("new_time", (F.unix_timestamp(df.Coltimestamp) + df.addHours*60*60).cast('timestamp')).show()
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|       Coltimestamp|addHours|           new_time|
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|2017-03-12 03:19:58|       2|2017-03-12 05:19:58|
|2017-03-12 03:21:30|       1|2017-03-12 04:21:30|
|2017-03-12 03:29:40|       3|2017-03-12 06:29:40|
|2017-03-12 03:31:23|       5|2017-03-12 08:31:23|
|2017-03-12 04:19:47|       6|2017-03-12 10:19:47|
|2017-03-12 04:33:51|       7|2017-03-12 11:33:51|
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
```